# Array.from vs Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So what is the difference between this two functions?

They both create `new Array` object. Only difference I found so far is that `Array.from` supports  `ArrayLike` parameters. I don't see any reason why they just haven't added `ArrayLike` support for `Array.prototype.map` function.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The purpose of `Array.from()` is to take a non-array (but array-like) object and make a copy of it into an actual array.  This then allows you to use ALL array methods on the copy including things beyond just iterating it such as `.splice()`, `.sort()`, `.push()`, `.pop()`, etc... which is obviously much more capable than just make `.map()` work with array-like things.

Comment: Great for things like DOM Nodelists and HTMLCollections that do not have things like map(), filter() or reduce()

Comment: A simple example: const a = Array.from("ABCDEFG") sets a = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

Answer (score 14):

Array.map seems to be a bit more performant as well:

```
var a = () => [{"count": 3},{"count": 4},{"count": 5}].map(item => item.count);
var b = () => Array.from([{"count": 3},{"count": 4},{"count": 5}], x => x.count);

var iterations = 1000000;
console.time('Function #1');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    b();
};
console.timeEnd('Function #1')

console.time('Function #2');
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
    a();
};
console.timeEnd('Function #2')
```

Running this code using Chrome (Version 65.0.3325.181) on this page gave me the follow results:

```
Function #1: 520.591064453125ms
Function #2: 33.622802734375ms
```

Comment: Comparison as of 2021-08-17
Chrome: 270ms vs 24,7ms
Firefox: 1032ms vs 727ms (might be my many plugins that create huge values.
Never the less the Chomevalues should also be in NodeJS and there it can really have a big impact

Answer (score 5):

**Static method vs instance method**

I know a lot of time has passed since the question was asked. A lot of good things have been said. But I would like to add some more. If we try to determine the nature of the two methods we can say that ***Array.from***
has no relation to any instance of Array. It is static method like ***Array.isArray*** or ***Array.of***. You also have static properties like *length* for the Array object. As a static method ***Array.from*** ***can not be Called from instance***.
For example:

```
var indexes=[0,1,2,3]
index.from()
>>> index.from is not a function
```

In the other hand if you write 
`Array.map()` you will end up with a `Array.map is not a function`. It is because ***Array.prototype.map*** Exist for the instance of array. In our little example indexes is an instance of Array then we use map on it.
Example

```
var indexes=[0,1,2,3]
function doubleIt(x){
    return 2*x;
}
indexes.map(doubleIt);
```

With array.from it shoud be something like

```
Array.from(indexes, doubleIt)
```

I used [quokka plugin](https://quokkajs.com/) on [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to evaluate performance on vs code in a windows machine. It is not real case of performance benchmarking. But it can help to have an idea.  I came up with the same conclusion as @rileynet map seem more performant but only for large array.

```
var N=10
var tabIndex=[ ...Array(N).keys()]

function doubleIt(x){
    return 2*x;
}
tabIndex.map(doubleIt);/*?.*/ 0.040ms

Array.from(tabIndex, doubleIt)/*?.*/ 0.009ms
```

if N=100

```
tabIndex.map(doubleIt);/*?.*/ 0.052ms

Array.from(tabIndex, doubleIt)/*?.*/ 0.041ms
```

if N=1000

```
tabIndex.map(doubleIt);/*?.*/ 0.228ms

Array.from(tabIndex, doubleIt)/*?.*/ 0.339ms
```

if N=10000

```
tabIndex.map(doubleIt);/*?.*/ 2.662ms

Array.from(tabIndex, doubleIt)/*?.*/ 1.847ms
```

N=100000

```
tabIndex.map(doubleIt);/*?.*/ 3.538ms

Array.from(tabIndex, doubleIt)/*?.*/ 11.742ms
```

Answer (score 4):

Making `Array.prototype` the prototype object for every single array-like "Class" in JS (more importantly, in DOM, where most of the 'array-like' objects live) would be a potential mistake.

What would a `.reduce( )` on a list of HTML elements/attributes look like?

`Array.from` is the official version of `[].slice.call(arrayLike);` with the added benefit of not having to create an unused array, just to create an array.

So really, `Array.from` can be polyfilled with `function (arrLike) { return [].slice.call(arrLike); }`, and minus native-implementation speed/memory improvements, it's the same result.

This has little to do with map|reduce|filter|some|every|find, which are the keys to living a long and happy life, without the need of micromanaging loops to get things done.