# Loop through an Array, add each item to an object and push it to an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, object

I have an array of ID's as below:

```
[121, 432, 322]
```

I want all of it to be added to an array in the following format **(Expected Output)**:

```
[
    {
        "term": {
            "brand_id": 121
        }
    },
    {
        "term": {
            "brand_id": 432
        }
    },
    {
        "term": {
            "brand_id": 322
        }
    }
]
```

I am able to get the structure right and get a result almost as expected. But am ending up having just the last value as the value in all items of the object as below **(Current Output)**:

```
[
        {
            "term": {
                "brand_id": 322
            }
        },
        {
            "term": {
                "brand_id": 322
            }
        },
        {
            "term": {
                "brand_id": 322
            }
        }
    ]
```

**My code is as below:**

> The array of IDs is in an array named brands.

```
let brands_formated = [];
//I have the array stored in `brands`
let format =  { "term" : {
                      "brand_id": 0 //will be replaced
                     }
              };

brands.forEach(function(brand) {
    //The structure for brand query
    format.term.brand_id = brand;
    //Check if the right brand is format. Outputs as desired.
    console.log(format);                            
    brands_formated.push(format);

});
```

Though `console.log` in loop confirms am iterating correctly. The final output just has one value.

Comment: you push the same object reference to the array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You currently only have one variable for `format` - you're only ever pushing one item to the array, you're just mutating it multiple times, resulting in the array containing 3 references to the same object.

Create the `format` on each iteration instead. `.map` is more appropriate than `.forEach` when transforming one array into another:

```js
const input = [121, 432, 322];
console.log(
  input.map(brand_id => ({ term: { brand_id }}))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51811976/2767755) answer explained the problem of your code. Here is my way to solve the same problem.

```
const input = [121, 432, 322];
Array.from(input, brand_id => ({ term: { brand_id }}))
```

Comment: Is there any reason use this over the other? Or a rule of thumb to decide which to use for what? 

As far as I understood, `Array.map` is a function similar to `Array.foreach` etc.., but more effecient. While `Array.from`is a method for making another array from an existing array/array-like objects.

Comment: Yes.. `Array.from` is a method for making another array from an existing array/array-like objects, using a map function which  is `brand_id => ({ term: { brand_id }})`.

Comment: @esafwan Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26053046/2767755) Best example of `Array.from` usage is [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrays.html#_mapping-via-arrayfrom)